# How do I end this game in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to end this game, it's in a loop, does anyone know which statement to add?  This is a quiz game I am doing for a school.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        /* Game rules */
        System.out.println("Here are the game rules: ");
        System.out.println("1. You do not have any power ups to use");
        System.out.println("2. You may only get one question wrong");
        System.out.println("3.If you get any question wrong, you will get what you win, and the game will end");
        System.out.println("Try your best to answer the questions");
        System.out.println("Type Start to begin");
        String start = input.next();
        String Question = null;
        String Questions = null;
        String word3 = null;
        if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
            System.out.println("What sport would you like to choose?");   // ask user what sport he wants
            System.out.println("A. Basketball     B. Soccer   C. Badminton");
            String sport = input.next();
            if (sport.equalsIgnoreCase("Badminton")) {  // if user wants Badminton 
                Badminton(Question);  // call method
            }
            if (sport.equalsIgnoreCase("Basketball")) {  // If user wants Basketball
                Basketball(Questions);  // call basketball method
            }
            if (sport.equalsIgnoreCase("Soccer")) {  // if user wants soccer
                Soccer(word3);  // call soccer method
            }
        }
```

Comment: He @Tony Chong: There is no loop? If there is one please copy also the loop itself to you example. Please describe also what are the exact rules (under which donditions should the loop be terminated). If you are just looking for a keyword `break` might be your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add a `return` statement each time you ask the user a question.  So when they get a question wrong, the game ends immediately and the prize is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a button and when user click on button so game will exit and score will be shown.

On button you add function like below..

```
System.exit(0);
```